# problem with Double and Rational Number

Tags: haskell, double, rational-number

I am writing a function in which I need to read a string contains floating point number and turn it back to Rational. But When I do `toRational (read input :: Double)`, it will not turn for eg: `0.9` into `9 % 10` as expected, but instead 81..... % 9007... 
Thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is correct behavior.  The number `0.9` is not representable as a `Double`, not in Haskell, C, or Java.  This is because `Double` and `Float` use base 2: they can only represent a certain subset of the dyadic fractions exactly.

To get the behavior you want, import the `Numeric` module and use the `readFloat` function.  The interface is fairly wonky (it uses the `ReadS` type), so you'll have to wrap it a little.  Here's how you can use it:

```
import Numeric
myReadFloat :: String -> Rational -- type signature is necessary here
myReadFloat str =
    case readFloat str of
      ((n, []):_) -> n
      _ -> error "Invalid number"
```

And, the result:

```
> myReadFloat "0.9"
9 % 10
```

Comment: If you want to handle negative numbers, use "readSigned readFloat".

Answer (score 2):

Binary floating point numbers cannot precisely represent all the numbers that base-10 can. The number you see as 0.9 is not *precisely* 0.9 but something very close to it. Never use floating-point types where decimal precision is needed — they just can't do it.